# PHP Fatal Error when trying to access a website on my computer with XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I have set up a website on my PC with XAMPP, MySQL and Apache enabled. I am getting this fatal error. I have set up the config files and followed the read-me correctly. However I cannot seem to get where the problem is. Database is correctly set up in config files and upload .sql to phpmyadmin.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\global.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\global.php(107): db_connection() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\index.php(9): include_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\global.php on line 29
```

Line 26-33 in global.php

```
function db_connection()
{
    global $config,$data_sql;
    $data_sql = mysql_connect($config["sql_host"], $config["sql_user"], $config["sql_pass"]);
    if (!$data_sql) die("Can't connect to MySql");
    mysql_select_db($config["db_name"],$data_sql) or die("Can't select database");
}
function db_close()
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? `mysql_connect()` was depreciated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7.0. You may want to use [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

Comment: `myql_connect()` is [deprecated](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) since php 5.5+ and removed in php 7. You can either use `mysqli_connect()` or `pdo` . If you still want to use mysql_connect() try with php<7(which I wouldn't recommend)

Comment: I added code to the post. I changed both mysql_connect and mysql_select_db to mysqli_connect and mysqli_select_db and the error disappeared but now it says Can't Select Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myql_connect() is deprecated since php 5.5+ and removed in php 7. You can either use mysqli_connect() or pdo . If you still want to use mysql_connect() try with php<7(which I wouldn't recommend)

Using [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php),

```
function db_connection()
{
    global $config,$data_sql;
    $data_sql = mysqli_connect($config["sql_host"], $config["sql_user"], $config["sql_pass"], $config["db_name"]); 
    // You can select the db, by passing it as 4th param if you like
    if (!$data_sql) die("Can't connect to MySql".mysqli_error($data_sql ) );

}
```

Comment: I just tried to use that and got a: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\global.php:109 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(8): include_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\global.php on line 109`

Comment: it should be `mysqli_query` . Every statement that starts with `mysql_` is deprecated and removed from php 7+

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. I changed everything that started with mysql_ to mysqli_ ; however now it shows: `Error, please contact webmaster for more information.`

Comment: @KingOfJe That might me an error you might be throwing. On which line does this exception is raised? Can you post the stack trace please? Check your `error.log` if you cant find an errors displayed in browser

Comment: I do not have an error.log, should I go thru every file that has mysql_ instead of mysqli_ and change it? Maybe that could be the problem?

Comment: Yes sir. Please try that. Also , error.log is generated by apache. It'll be located somewhere  in `C:\xampp\apache\logs`

Comment: @KingOfJe can you post the code your actually trying to execute?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zpnx5nuK - the code i am trying to execute (global.php)

And the error in the logs is the last thing I pasted here and it is fixed. No errors in the logs since then. But I get the `Error, please contact webmaster for more information.`

Comment: @KingOfJe set `$config["show_error"] = false;` to true , You'll get the error displayed . Also , myqli_query takes `connection` as first parameter. not sql query

Comment: Or put this at the top `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I changed the show error to true and now it displays this: https://pastebin.com/DB0uFqPS | and sorry where have I made a mistake with parameters?

Comment: Sounds like your entire 'global.php' file is a mess

Comment: Yep Issac is right :) Your config array has no entry for `localhost` , `username`, `pwhere ` , `db` .

Comment: How do I add the entries? Would switching to XAMPP with PHP < 5.5.0 fix the problem?

Comment: Nope. I'm afraid it won't.  Declare it similar to $config . Example, $config['username']= 'root';

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil - I added     `$config["localhost"] = "localhost";
    $config["username"] = "root";
    $config["pwhere"] = "";
    $config["db"] = "demo";` to the beginning of the global.php file and now it's working! Thank you very much!

Comment: @KingOfJe no worries .I'm glad I was of any help!

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connect is depreciated as far as i'm aware from php 7+.  Try to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) it's more secure and people will shout at you if you try to use **mysql_connect** if you're running an older version of php. A quick google search would've found this quote in the php documentation.

> Warning
>   This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

In response to your comment, here's a PDO example of a typical connection to the database

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "root";
$dbname = "dbname";

try{
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$dbusername, 
$dbpassword);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
print "Error! Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
?>
```

Edit the variables to suit your needs at the top, provided the details are correct the only thing that needs to be changed are the

```
$servername 
$dbusername 
$dbpassword 
$dbname
```

Comment: I added code to the post. I changed both mysql_connect and mysql_select_db to mysqli_connect and mysqli_select_db but now it says Can't Select Database.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer, it uses PDO. This is just down to my preference.

Comment: I added that between function db_connection and db_close, edited the $servername $dbusername etc and now I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$servername' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\global.php on line 27`